# What's equivalent of C# NetworkInterface in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, network-programming, delphi-10.3-rio

What's equivalent of [`NetworkInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface?view=net-7.0) in Delphi, where i can build a program like 
[**Network-Bandwidth-Meter**](https://github.com/ewwink/Network-Bandwidth-Meter)
?

There some way to use this class on Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/NetworkInterface.cs) for the `NetworkInterface` class, you will see that internally it gets its information from the [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) function, which you can call directly in Delphi code.